# Validating a Rails form field that has to run through another model before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails (Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.1) application which deals with flights; among other things, it has a `Flight` model and an `Airline` model, with `Flight belongs_to :airline` and `Airline has_many :flights`. `Airline` has an `iata_code` column which contains the two-letter IATA airline code (i.e. `AA`, `UA`, `WN`, `F9`).

For the flight entry form, I want the user to be able to enter an arbitrary IATA code, rather than selecting an airline from a dropdown. If the IATA code the user enters matches a record in the `Airline` table, then the `Flight.airline_id` column should be set to that airline's ID. If the IATA code *doesn't* match an airline in my database, then the airline should be created using the IATA code provided, and that new airline's ID should be assigned to `Flight.airline_id`.

I currently have this working by having an Airline IATA code field in my add/edit flight form (note that the form field is named `:airline_iata` instead of `:airline_id`):

```
<%= f.label :airline_iata, "Airline code" %>
<%= f.text_field :airline_iata, class: "form-control code airline-iata", maxlength: 2, placeholder: 'AA' %>
```

Then, in my Flights controller's `create` and `update` action, I try to look up the airline before I save the flight, and set the `airline_id` parameter (`create` is below, but `update` is similar):

```
def create
  params[:flight][:airline_id] = Airline.find_or_create_by!(:iata_code => params[:flight][:airline_iata].upcase).id
  @flight = current_traveler.flights.build(flight_params)

  if @flight.save
    redirect_to event_path(current_traveler.event)
  else
    render "new"
  end

end
```

This approach is working for me, **except** that I am unable to figure out how to do validation on the Airline IATA code field **from the flight form**. The Airline model validates the code (`presence: true, length: { is: 2 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }`), so if the user inputs an invalid IATA code, the Airline creation will fail, and thus the Flight creation will fail. However, I won't get the usual validation errors on the Flight form (e.g. error message, form fields with errors highlighted) since Flight's problem is that the `airline_id` (which isn't directly on the Flight form) isn't present, rather than that `airline_iata` in the Flight form is invalid.

How can I set it up so that this form field that has to interact with the Airport model before submission can run the Airport model's validation on a Flight form field, and return form validation errors accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use nested form attributes and add before_validation hook which will override the association:

```
<%= f.fields_for :airline do |airline_form| %>
  <%= airline_form.label :iata_code, "Airline code" %>
  <%= airline_form.text_field :iata_code %>
<% end %>
```

In flight.rb you should have

```
accept_nested_attributes_for :airline
before_validation :check_existing_airline, on: :create

def check_existing_airline
  if airline.new_record? && existing_airline = Airline.find_by(iata_code: airline.iata_code)
    self.airline = exisitng_airline
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed; thanks. I did get tripped up for a while by forgetting that I also needed to add `airline_attributes: [:iata_code]` to the flight_params hash, so if anyone else has issues, remember to check your params hash.